# VB6: Surely this simple Hex addition is wrong?

Tags: vb6, hex

I'm getting odd results in some VB6 code which I've narrowed to this:

```
Debug.Print Hex(&hEDB80000 + &h8300)
```

Shows **EDB78300**

That can't by right can it? Surely it should be **EDB88300**?

Am I going mad?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't forget how [negative numbers are expressed in binary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement), and that VB6 and VB.NET interpret numbers like &h8300 differently.

Because &hEDB80000 doesn't fit in 16-bits, VB interprets it as a **long** (32-bits).  Because the high bit is set, VB6 knows it's negative.

Let's undo the [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) (in a 32-bit world) to figure out the decimal value

```
(~&hEDB80000 + 1) = &h1247FFFF + 1 = &h12480000 = 306708480
```

since the sign bit was set, that's **-306708480**

Because &h8300 fits in 16-bits, VB interprets it as an **integer** (16-bits).  Because the high bit is set, VB6 knows that it's negative.

Let's undo the two's complement (in a *16-bit* world)

```
(~&h8300 + 1) = &h7DFF + 1 = &h7D00 = 32000
```

since the sign bit was set, that's **-32000**.  When the addition happens, both values are considered to be longs (32-bits).

```
(-306708480) + (-32000) = -306740480
```

Let's put that back into two's complement hex

```
~(306740480 - 1) = ~(&h12487D00 - 1) = ~(&h12487CFF) = &hEDB78300
```

So **&hEDB78300** is the correct answer.

---

Notes:

I personally thing the confusion happens because of the following:

```
&h0004000 is interpreted as  16384 // Fits in 16-bits, sign bit is not set
&h0008000 is interpreted as -32768 // Fits in 16-bits, sign bit is set
&h0010000 is interpreted as  65536 // Requires 32-bits, sign bit is not set
```

as mentioned in the other post, you can get around this by explicitly marking values as longs

```
&h0004000& is interpreted as  16384 
&h0008000& is interpreted as  32768 
&h0010000& is interpreted as  65536
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?  I'm not seeing how the result of anything negative plus a small positive number would end with the same small number.  (Switching to base10...  -1000 + 97 = 903, not something ending with 97.)  His output ends with "8300", which is the number he added.

Comment: I've done the math in a hex calc and I get his expected result.  I must not be seeing the forest for the trees.

Comment: @JMD: VB6 does things kind of weird, and interprets 0x8300 as a negative number, so it comes out strange

Comment: @JMD: because the version ofg this answer you were reading was inaccurate.  Daniel has since made an attempt at correcting it but seems to be overcomplicating it.

Comment: @daniel:  There is nothing weird or strange about it.  Its not 0x8300 VB doesn't know what that is, its &h8300 which is an interger value of -32000, whats strange about that?

Comment: @Anthony: I think it feels strange if you're coming back to VB6 from VB.NET where &H8300 is interpreted as 33536, _not_ -32000

Answer (score 3):

Fundementally because VB6 sees &h8300 as an integer having the value -32000.  To get the results you were expecting you would need to explictly mark it as a Long:-

```
Debug.Print Hex(&hEDB80000 + &h8300&)
```

What your were doing was adding a Long to an Interger.  To do that VB6 first extends the Integer to a Long, since &h8300 represents a negative number the Long it is converted to ends up with the value &hFFFF8300.  Armed with that value you can see that the result returned by VB6 is correct.

```
FF + B8 = B7 with carry bit set
FF + ED + carry bit = ED
```

Comment: +1 for being succinct.  (also, I think you're missing an h on &EDB80000)